# ocaml - unbound value error in recursive list matching function

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I copied a recursive list matching function from a slide of an introductory ocaml course.

```
let rec fac n = match n with
     0 -> 1
     | _ -> n * fac(n-1);;

fac 3;;
```

I get: "Error: Unbound value fac"

Why is this?

Comment: This works fine for me. How are you using this?

Comment: I'm using it in emacs in tuareg mode

Comment: ok, if I run it in the interactive mode, it works. But if I run it from the editor it doesn't

Comment: I'll bet you forgot to put `rec` keyword when you ran it. It's one of the common mistakes for this error message.

Comment: You have to explain exactly what you did in Emacs.  I roughly guess you might execute `tuareg-eval-phrase` only on `fac 3`, not evaluating the function definition prior to it.

Comment: this might be the case, i'll test it

Answer (score 0):

Using M-X tuareg-eval-buffer in emacs gives:

```
        OCaml version 4.02.3

# let rec fac n = match n with
     0 -> 1
     | _ -> n * fac(n-1);;

fac 3;;
    val fac : int -> int = <fun>
#   - : int = 6
#
```

You probably run M-X tuarge-eval-region with only the `fac 3` selected so the function was never defined.